# How to create a library that improves the official TextInput component in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I've added a small feature that improves the UX of the `<TextInput>` component in React Native. The new code is in the native side so I had to make changes to several files inside official `RCTText` library.

Currently, I got this working locally by manually changing the code inside `node_modules` and rebuilding the project. I plan to make a PR to the official React Native project once I fix all the edge cases. I understand that sometimes features takes a while to make it into the official release(if at all) so in the meantime, I would like to release this `improved <TextInput>`as a library for other's that might be interested.

The goal is to release a library that once added to project will allow you to create a `<MyTextInput>` component which does everything the original `<TextInput>` does. And here is where I got a bit lost. Can someone please point me to the right direction on how to make a library out of this, or perhaps a link to a library that does a similar thing(augmenting an official RN component in native code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can bootstrap a linkable library project using [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library) and then copy your modified [RCTText library project](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Text) into it.

You'll want to rename the library, e.g. by giving it a prefix other than RCT to avoid collisions with the main RCTText component. Additionally, you'll need to rename all the references to the RCT* components in the source files.

Once you have created the library, you can publish it to NPM and install it to your React Native app with:

```
npm install your-text-component
react-native link your-text-component
```

I haven't tried this for built-in React components, but releasing a third-party native library for React Native should not really be any different, whether or not the original implementation is based on existing React Native component or not.